# Keep getting this error when i try to load an image asset "Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assests/1.png)"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to load an image but i keep getting this error Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assests/1.png),

this is what  have tried so far, the image is located in my assets folder in my root directory

```
name: wallet_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0
  provider: ^3.0.0+1
  email_validator: ^1.0.0
  bubble_bottom_bar: ^1.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.0.1
  flutter_icons : 1.1.0
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  firebase_core : ^0.5.0



  








  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter  


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  assets:
   - assets/1.png
   - assets/newdp.png

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and this is how i implement it

```
 return  Container( 
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
       child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               Center( 
              child: Image.asset(
              "assests/1.png",
              width: 600.0,
              height: 240.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),),

            Center( child:Text("Hello tlululuhere"))]));
```

........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: did you try to clean the project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre getting the wrong path:

```
Image.asset(
              "assests/1.png",
```

must be :

```
Image.asset(
              "assets/1.png",
```